# Can we set local environment in anaconda like in pyenv?

Tags: python, anaconda, pyenv

does `anaconda` support setting local environment like `pyenv`?
like `pyenv local py37` then when I enter this folder the environment will be automatically switched to `py37` and when I exit, it's reset to be `base`.

UPDATE:
please notice the point here is **automatically**, I know how to switch them **manually**. But I get tired of typing commands, so I want `anaconda` switches environment for me **automatically**, according to my current directory

Comment: Sometimes I wish we could close answers when the answer is the *first* result on google. There you go https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Comment: @BlackBear How does that link help this poster? I don't see any results in there that tell whether or not environments can be activated upon entering a folder in the terminal...

Comment: @BlackBear I have read that, but I don't think that gives a word about how to automatically switch environment

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would be:

```
conda activate py37
```

And going out:

```
conda deactivate
```

See: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Update: I assumed that you have created an environment called py37 as:

```
conda create -n py37 python=3.7
```

Update:
To set it to do automatic in Windows you can set it to be first in priority on your path

```
setx PATH "%userprofile%\Anaconda3\envs\py37\;%PATH%"
setx PATH "%userprofile%\Anaconda3\envs\py37\Scripts;%PATH%"
```

In Linux, you would add it in .bashrc see https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#440-2017-12-20

Comment: sorry, I mean **automatically** instead of **manually** switching environment.